# How to change ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> to DoubleBinding

Tags: javafx, binding

How to change ObjectProperty to DoubleBinding  and then put into Bindings.createObjectBinding();

```
private transient ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  buy;
private transient ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  sell;
```

There are the mistake:

```
buy = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> (operation.get() == Operation.BUY) ? volume.get() : 0, volume, operation);

sell = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> (operation.get() == Operation.SELL) ? volume.get() : 0, volume, operation);
```

Comment: From private transient DoubleBinding buy;

Comment: to private transient ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  buy;